# Quota action script with Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: scripting, quota

I am using Windows 2008 R2 Server. I used quota manangement in shared folder. My requirement is, whenever the limit is exceeded, .bat file should run.

My current batch file code is

```
@echo off
start "C:\scripts" xyz.exe
exit
```

I want to open the exe file, whenever the quota limit exceeds.

I am new to scripting. I don't know how to pass command line arguments here.

Can anybody help me on this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please post your script?  It is pretty much impossible to troubleshoot an unknown script...

Comment: code is only this much i ve written in bat file.

======================

@echo off

start "C:\" xyz.exe %*

=======================

Answer (score 1):

To pass on all parameters to the script use `%*`

Like this:

```
@echo off
start "C:\scripts" xyz.exe %*
```

[Reference](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 1):

Ok if you are just trying to run the exe from the bat file then your bat file should just look like this inside:

```
C:\xyz.exe
```

If you want to pass parameters to the batch file then you can either do what Peter suggested (which I wasn't aware of so thanks Peter), or put each parameter individually in the batch file like so:

```
C:\xyz.exe %1 %2 %3
```

This will enable you to call the batch file like so:

```
xyz.bat param1 param2 param3
```

I put the params after the exe but you can put them wherever you need them to be in the bat file like so: (this example has the 1st parameter as the folder name, 2nd as the name of the exe, and 3rd as a param to pass to the exe).

```
C:\%1\%2.exe %3
```

You could call the batch file like so:

```
xyz.bat <folder name> <exe name> <parameter>
```